# Is there a way to implement a bottom-up event notification in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a container control (TLayout or TPanel or TScrollbox, etc.) which can have several other nested controls inside. Is there a way in Firemonkey to know when the container becomes "active"? I mean for example:

- when any of its children get focus or
- user clicks any of its non-focus controls

I am asking for a kind of event-bubble. OnClick would be enough so when user clicks any nested control, the parent container is notified. Control's HitTest property would be a solution but if I set that property to False (to let the parent manages the onlick) on a TEdit, it becomes useless obviously (I can't type on it)

**Edit:**

A simple layout example:

- Drop a TScrollBox in a form
- Drop a TPanel in form and put it as child of the TScrollBox
- Drop a TEdit in form an put it as child of TPanel

Ok, I can simply do a sort of Parent.Parent.Click after receive the OnClick on TEdit but imagine now several TScrollBoxes, with different level of nesting using TPanels with a bunch of different controls inside. It doesn't make sense neither adding the onclick code for each control in the tree, nor change the hierarchy of Parent.Parent.Click every time I redesign the layout adding an intermediate parent control.

Is there any way to do this in Firemonkey (either for Windows or MacOS)?

PS: I'm using Delphi 10.2.3 (Tokyo)

Comment: No, nothing readily existing. What would you do with that event in the parent chain of the actual clicked component? IOW, why would you need this?

Comment: I want to simulate a little windows inside the main form of my application so that when the user clicks a child control I want to know that at the top parent control level then change the "title bar" color to simulate focus but this need can be applied on several scenarios.

Comment: Well, not sure I get it, but 1) You can traverse through all parents by recursively calling `GetParentComponent`. 2) On a form you can directly access any other component on the form. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Not enough information, really. How is the container defined? i.e. is it a certain type of control? Is it defined by being parented to some other control, or by being parented to the form? A solution cannot be devised until that is known.

Comment: I just outlined the problem in a manner that can be assemble as anyone like, e.g. Drop a TScrollBox in a form, then put a TPanel as child of the TScrollBox, then a TEdit as a child of TPanel. I want to know if there is a native, simple or automatic way in FM to trigger the TScrollBox.OnClick (top parent) when the user clicks the TEdit. Ok, I can simply call the Parent.Parent.Click event after receive the OnClick on TEdit but imagine now several distinct TPanel with different level of nesting with a bunch of different controls inside. It doesn't make sense do it in that way.

Comment: An example of a simple and native way to do what I'm looking for is the control property HitTest. It is enough to set that property to False on the TPanel and TEdit in the example I described above to let the TScrollbox to manage the OnClick event of its children. The problem is that in that way, the TEdit doesn't work, i.e. you can't type characters.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question instead of adding details here in the comments. And please also avoid repeating yourself, you already said why using the `HitTest` property is a no go. And, it may also be a good idea to say what platforms you intend this for.

Comment: My intention with the way I wrote the question was to summarize the problem in general words to non overwhelming the people with a long text. The example I put in comments is quite obviously after someone read carefully the description. Anyway I am the needy so I will follow your advices.